# Remove Class from div on hover

Tags: jquery

I am a noob at jquery and have been frustrated as hell trying to get the following to work.  I am sure it is something simple that an experienced developer would pick up straight away.

I have a menu in 1 list and lists in other divs on the page.  When the user hovers over the menu, items in the lists are to be highlighted.  I have got this far.  But because the lists are long, I need a click event to also highlight the items while the user scrolls down the page.

That's ok.  But I cannot work out how to remove the click class from the highlighted items when they user over over the next item in the menu.

```
$('#buttons li').hover(function () {
    $('.item-' + this.className).addClass('clients-hover');
},
function () {
    $('.item-' + this.className).removeClass('clients-hover');
});
$(function() {
  $('#buttons li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('clients-hover');
  });
});
```

For example, in the fiddle below, when the User hovers or clicks on Artists/Bands the items in the divs light up, but when the user hovers over Comedians, the items in that class are highlighted and the Artists/Bands return to normal.

http://jsfiddle.net/toddyhotpants/RCMaP/4/

This is it on the page (without the click event):
http://whitesky.com.au/clients/

thanks in advance.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/RCMaP/7/

Answer (score 3):

Just remove class `clients-hover` of other siblings of clicked element:

```
$(this).addClass('clients-hover').siblings().removeClass('clients-hover');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RCMaP/6/

---

Based on your comment, just need to modify your code when hover on the menu nav:

```
$('#buttons li').hover(function () {
    $('.item-' + this.className).addClass('clients-hover')
    .parent().siblings().children().removeClass('clients-hover');
},

function () {
    $('.item-' + this.className).addClass('clients-hover');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RCMaP/12/

Comment: Hi, Thanks that is almost it.  But maybe I was not exactly clear, I need the list items in the 'items' div to lose their hover/clicked state when the user hovers over the menu nav.

Comment: thanks, that's great.  although I can't get this working properly in the wordpress site, any ideas?  [http://whitesky.com.au/clients/](http://whitesky.com.au/clients/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.toggleClass()` instead of $.addClass() :)

[Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/RCMaP/5/)

Comment: Your code will not remove class `clients-hover` of siblings of clicked element

Answer (score 0):

use `siblings()` to remove class of others in click event.. updated some of your codes .. you don't need two document.ready function....

try this

```
$('#buttons li').hover(function () {
   $("div[class^='item']").removeClass('clients-hover'); //<--here removesclass from all div
    $('.item-' + this.className).addClass('clients-hover');
},

$(function () {
  $('.item-' + this.className).removeClass('clients-hover'); // moved for other document.ready function 
  $('#buttons li').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('clients-hover'); //<--- here remove class from other li 
    $(this).addClass('clients-hover');
  });
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/RCMaP/8/)

Comment: Your code broken if you click on list element then hover on other elements then it will no longer highlight the item on the right side

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('#buttons li').hover(function () {
    $('.item-' + this.className).addClass('clients-hover');
    },
    function () {
    $('.item-' + this.className).removeClass('clients-hover');
});

$(function() {
   $('#buttons li').click(function() {
      $("[class^=item]").not($('.item-' + this.className)).removeClass('clients-hover');
      $(this).addClass('clients-hover');
      $(this).siblings().removeClass('clients-hover');
      $('.item-' + this.className).addClass('clients-hover');
   });
});
```

Comment: thanks Bhuwan - that works great in the fiddle, but I can't get it to work in my wordpress site.  it's driving me crazy.  the items on the right hold their styling after the click, but the items in the menu nav don't.  I can't work out where I am going wrong.  here it is in the site: [http://vnpropaganda.com/whitesky/clients/](http://vnpropaganda.com/whitesky/clients/)